# JavaScript random number based on condition outputs unexpected behaviour

Tags: javascript

**UPDATED**: (real environment with real issue)

http://citibigreveal.stage.aiareview.co.uk/

when you click on any of the 4 options at the bottom you will see the console.log values coming from:

```
var Utilities = (function (array, maxN) {

  function generateRandomNumber(array, maxN) {
        let randomN = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxN) + 0;
        console.log(array.length);
        console.log(maxN);

        if(array.length == maxN) {
            array.length = 0;
        }

        if(!array.includes(randomN)) {
            array.push(randomN);
        }
        else {
            randomN = generateRandomNumber(array, maxN);
        }
        return randomN;
    }

    return {
        generateRandomNumber: generateRandomNumber
    };

})();

export default Utilities;
```

the unexpected behaviour is that the array is randomly set to 0 (that should only happen when its length is equal to maxN passed in)

the following function makes use of that utility:

```
var cityArray = [];

function getRandomNumber() {
    let randomN = Utilities.generateRandomNumber(cityArray, 10);
    return randomN;
}
```

and it is called within a react component as so:

```
...
getNewQuestion = () => {
    var randomN = getRandomNumber();
    var catArray = this.state.data.data.questions;
    Shuffle(catArray);
    this.setState({
        question: catArray[randomN]
    })
    this.setCatBgColor(catArray[randomN].category);
}
...
```

the ideal scenario is:

- for every random number generated return it
- if that number has been already generated store it inside an array and generate a new random number until the ma length is reached. 
  You will also notice that sometimes maxN will be 24. (That is really strange as the inserted max value is 10) as per:

  ```
  function getRandomNumber() {
      let randomN = Utilities.generateRandomNumber(cityArray, 10);
      return randomN;
  }
  ```

Comment: What did you expect? `generateRandomNumber` is recursive, it calls itself... Of course the logging statements are going to be called more than once if the function is called more than once.

Comment: Also, why did you re-post this question? Why did you delete [your old one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46847340/js-generate-random-number-based-on-condition)?

Comment: That question was closed by somebody. @Cerbrus

Comment: It wasn't closed. It had only 1 close-_vote_. A close-vote that might have been retracted after you edited the question to provide a proper [mcve].

Comment: why not you comment the code `console.log(array.length);
        console.log(maxN);` and print only returned value  ?

Comment: As per your code, some cases generateRandomNumber  function will execute multiple times in a single click. So what you are trying to do?

Comment: @Alex The biggest problem with this question is that the context is missing. We don't know how you want to implement this code, so giving advise is hard. This is why people put close votes on it. As in relation to your title: the code isn't doing anything unexpected.

Comment: @Cerbrus This question is a different question to what that question originally was. He was originally asking about an issue where-by `maxN` had become some unexpected value. This question is different... an improvement, even.

Comment: @Cerbrus We can try to guide him towards debugging problems by minimisation, and it seems he responds well. That should be celebrated. I wonder what kind of message would be sent by drilling into someone after they've tried to comply with excessively stringent requirements and made leaps and bounds, for example... What behaviour should we try to encourage, to foster? Let us not seek to become an emotional StackOverflow; keep StackOverflow *informational* and *relevant*.

Comment: @Sebivor: This question is a literal copy of the deleted one. It is generally frowned upon to delete and re-post a question. I'm not sure why you claim we're going emotional here...

Comment: I have updated my question with the real scenario. Hopefully this will make things more clear. Thanks for all of your help

Comment: @Cerbrus I saw the original question, prior to its crippling edit which made it look a lot like this one. Prior to the edits, it was a different question. I was actually contemplating rolling back the edits and asking OP to try again, because that kind of *question changing* is not what the *edit* feature is meant for.

Comment: @Alex I disagree that I will notice something `maxN` will be 24. I'm more inclined to agree that your RAM is faulty, or that your particular implementation of JS has some seriously crippling bugs which you should *run away from*... Do a (lengthy; make it at least an hour) test of your memory, and measure your voltage rails at the same time, make sure your computer is functioning sanely...

Answer (score 0):

> the console.log staments inside "generateRandomNumber" are being outputted multiple times

This is because you made that function recursive. In this line of code you made the function call itself: `randomN = generateRandomNumber(array, maxN);`

... and so the function is called more than once, there will be more than one print message.

> How can I fix this?

If you want to move the print message to outside of the loop, then, well... I think you'll work out how to do that. This work is a solid step in the direction of functional programming. Keep up the good work :)

Better still, these lines appear as though they're for highly specific debugging/experimenting purposes, and if you're no longer using them for debugging or experimenting you can (and should) remove them. Yeh. That'll fix your problem.

Comment: `array.length = 0;` is quite common to "wipe" an array. It does discard the elements: `const a = [1,2,3,4]; a.length = 0; console.log([2]);`

Comment: @Cerbrus Okay... You *got* me! No, seriously, though... you're right. My memory must not be as bright as it once was. Such is the wonder of being a human, eh? We all get to age ;) `console.log([2]);` seriously? Why bother logging that? What's your point? So you can display `[2]`... how relevant?

Comment: Eh, typo, that was supposed to be `a[2]`

Comment: @Cerbrus Nonetheless, you might have noticed I edited that section of my answer out. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not seem broken, at least, you haven't specified what it *should* be doing compared to what it is doing currently.

As has been pointed out, `generateRandomNumber` is recursive, and the multiple log outputs you are seeing are an effect of that. If you want to "fix" that, get rid of the outputs and e.g. only log the array at the end:

```
var array = [];

$("div").on('click', function(){
  console.log('clicked');
  generateRandomNumber(array, 10);
  console.log(array);
})
```